# Cannot get series highcharts with DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, highcharts

I want to create button (with DOM) for hide all series from highcharts.

my script on tampermonkey (DOM function):

```
$(function() {
    $("<button id='button'>Hide Series</button>").prependTo(".stats-highchart-wrapper");

    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    $(document).on('click', '#button', function() {
        $.each(chart.series, function(i, ser) {
            ser.hide();
        });
    });
});
```

But the result always show error like this
[ERROR: Execution of script 'Highcharts' failed! Cannot read property 'series' of undefined]

Comment: The error saying that the `chart` is not a valid highchart object.

Comment: Could you show your whole code? Current code does not create any chart. Just a lucky guess, move `var chart = ... ` into the callback, maybe chart is not defined when you init event.